# Slidedown issue in jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidedown

This is my html code:

```
<div class="c-service-header">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Shipping and returns</h1>
</div>
<div class="c-service-content">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="c-service-header">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Payment</h1>
</div>
<div class="c-service-content">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

This is the css code:

```
.c-service-header{cursor:pointer;width:400px;border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1}
.c-service-content{display:none;}
```

And the jquery code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() { 
        jQuery(".c-service-header").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).next('.c-service-content').slidedown(3000);
        });
    });
```

I have included this jquery version:`//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`, but I am getting this erros message:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).next(...).slidedown is not a function
```

If I write I want to show the content of the c-service-content, like this:

```
jQuery(this).next('.c-service-content').show();
```

it works. So is smth wrong with the slidedown. Can someone give some idea ? thx

Comment: Changing it to `slideDown()` should work - note the capital D

Comment: Woaw thx a lot , its time for me to go home, drink smth and continue it tomorrow :D